# Convert String to Algebraic Expression in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a simple differentiation function

```
def differentiate(func, num) -> float:
    x = num
    h = 0.000000001
    der = (func(x+h)-func(x))/h
    return round(der,4)

print(differentiate(lambda x: x+5,10))
```

Which gives the expected output of `1.0` But I want to make the `func` argument such that it only needs the expression to be in the form of a string. For example:

```
print(differentiate('x+5', 10))
```

Is this possible to do? Preferably without the help of modules.

Comment: You might find sympy interesting...

Comment: I looked into it, and I saw that it would be what I needed but I was trying to go through a library-less approach if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether x is always your variable. If it is the case, then you can use the [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function of python which parses your string and evaluate it as a python expression:

```
def differentiate(func_x, num) -> float:
   x = num
   h = 0.000000001
   func = lambda x: eval(func_x)
   der = (func(x+h)-func(x))/h
   return round(der,4)
print(differentiate('x+5', 10))
>>> 1.0
```

Edit:
As [Serge Ballesta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta) pointed out below, the eval function may have security issues as it allows uncontrolled execution at run time, i.e. it will execute any piece of code given in input, so only use it if you can trust the input of your function.

Comment: `eval` works but I read somewhere that it is unsafe to use as it can take any valid python code as input and can cause error. Either way thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm... this is close to my (later) answer. But yours fails to warn that `eval` has security implications and why. If you improve your answer with such a warning, I could upvote this answer and remove mine (just ping me in a comment if you do...)

Comment: `func = lambda x: eval(func_x)` is much slower than `func = eval(f"lambda x: {func_x}")`, if you're planning on calling `func` more than once. The overhead of `eval` is enormous compared to the actual evaluation.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks for the comment, I updated my answer.